# Lucene query for array and "IN", "ALL IN", "ANY IN" operations

Tags: lucene

I need to implement the following predicate with Lucene query language:

```
{param} IN optionIds
```

where `{param}` is my external parameter and `optionIds` is an array(or collection).

for example I have the document with the following `optionIds`:

```
"optionIds": [
    72,
    44,
    11,
    9,
    10
  ]
```

The following Lucene predicate `optionIds:72` correctly returns this document.

But how to return this document based on the follownig values: 72, 11, 9

The following predicate `optionIds:72, 11, 9` doesn't work and the Lucene query returns the empty result.

Please show how to properly use(emulate) `IN` operation in Lucene query language with arrays(collections). Also, please show how to use `ALL IN/ANY IN`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To match any of the query terms to list in the document:

```
optionIds:(72 11 9)
```

To match all of the query terms:

```
optionIds:(+72 +11 +9)
```

Comment: Would you happen to know where this is mentioned in official Lucene docs? I failed to find a page listing all Lucene syntax on Google.

Comment: @DanielCheung - Sure thing: https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.lucene/lucene-queryparser/8.8.1/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html